# How to call a method of Vue js by clicking a button from inside the google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I am using a package named [vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps) for developing an application.

I added a code snippet for adding few button inside the map but when I click on the button then it does not call any method of vue. How may I solve the problem

**Here is my code**

```
let search_result = document.createElement('div');
search_result.style.width = '300px';
search_result.style.margin = '10px';
search_result.style.fontSize = '16px';
search_result.style.backgroundColor = '';
search_result.style.cursor = 'pointer';
search_result.innerHTML = ' <button @click="test()" class="btn-primary" id="reset"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reset </button>
<button @click="handleUndo()" class="btn-primary" id="undo"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i> Undo </button>
<button @click="polygon_redo()" class="btn-primary" id="redo"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i> Redo </button> ';

this.$refs.gmap.$mapObject.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(search_result);

drawingManager.setMap(this.$refs.gmap.$mapObject)
```

**Problem:** When I click on the undo, redo, reset button then it does not call any method's of vue js.

I need suggestion, how may I add button or any pop up inside the google map who can interact with vue instance properties or methods, it would be two way data binding

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?  I.e. your main Vue instance, template etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue, you should never add markup by `createElement` method (or in any other way directly from script). Generally, markup should be in your `<template>`. The markup you created is not reactive or accessible by Vue, because it was added outside of the component initialization scope.
Check out Vuejs docs for more detail: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

To solve you problem in a valid "Vue way", you need to show more content, preferably a full component.

Comment: Here is my methods, 
https://jsbin.com/qopohasiwu/edit?js

I mentioned that I used vue map package where I can use their components.

Comment: I assume your sample only shows a single method, you would need to provide code for your full component (including template) to make any sense of it.